# Basic keyframe animation (rotation)

Tags: iphone, core-animation

I'm trying to create a very simple keyframe animation, whereby a graphic Rotates from one angle to another, through a given midpoint.

(The purpose is to be able to animate rotation through an <strike>OBTUSE</strike> angle of arc GREATER THAN 180 DEGREES, rather than having the animation 'cheat' and go the shortest route, i.e., via the opposite <strike>, ACUTE</strike> smaller angle -- which can happen when there's only one [i.e, destination] keyframe.  To go the 'long' way around, I assume I need an extra keyframe midway through, along the *desired* arc.)

Here's what I've got so far (which does get the graphic to the desired rotation, via the most acute angle):

```
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(__ANGLE__) ((__ANGLE__) / 180.0 * M_PI)

...

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
CGAffineTransform cgCTM = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(desiredEndingAngle));
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
graphic.transform = cgCTM;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

As I understand it, I’m not looking for animation along a Path (since that’s for Translation, rather than Rotation) ...

Anyway, any help would be VERY much appreciated!  Thanks in advance.

Comment: One quick clarification (as it's been a while since I took Geometry!). The purpose is to Rotate the needle on a SPEEDOMETER-type gauge, whose markings cover MORE THAN 180 DEGREES.  As it is now, when the needle goes from near 0 to near Max, it takes the shortest distance to get there ... thus, crossing thru the "6 o'clock" region, where there are no markings (e.g., where it says "MPH" instead). I need a way, essentially, specify which DIRECTION that rotation happens. Presumably, that means Clockwise/Counterclockwise, or thru a specified midpoint.  Hence, the idea of an extra keyframe.  Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Think I’ve got it.

Here’s code which does (in this example) a full 270 DEGREE rotation (1.5*pi radians), including various parameters that can be customized further:

```
CALayer *layer = rotatingImage.layer;
CAKeyframeAnimation *animation;
animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
animation.duration = 0.5f;
animation.cumulative = YES;
animation.repeatCount = 1;
animation.values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:       // i.e., Rotation values for the 3 keyframes, in RADIANS
      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0 * M_PI], 
      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.75 * M_PI], 
      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.5 * M_PI], nil]; 
animation.keyTimes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:     // Relative timing values for the 3 keyframes
      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0], 
      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:.5], 
      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], nil]; 
animation.timingFunctions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
      [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn],    // from keyframe 1 to keyframe 2
      [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut], nil]; // from keyframe 2 to keyframe 3
animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

[layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
```

Thanks!

Comment: This works for [rotating by 360 degrees](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1216951/1309352).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UIImageView* rotatingImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init]];
[rotatingImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"]];

CATransform3D rotationTransform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(1.0f * M_PI, 0, 0, 1.0);
CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];

rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:rotationTransform];
rotationAnimation.duration = 0.25f;
rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
rotationAnimation.repeatCount = 1;

[rotatingImage.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
```

Comment: Hi, Nathan! Thanks so much for the response and your expertise.  I'm getting the following Error on the last line: "request for member 'layer' in something not a structure or union".  I imagine I'm missing some other setup (as UIImage doesn't normally have a Layer property). Being brand new to Core Animation, am still a bit stuck.  [Also not sure as yet how this specifies a midpoint, or alternatively, a DIRECTION for the rotation (essentially a choice of Clockwise or Counterclockwise), but I'm sure it'll become apparent once I can get this to run.]  Many thanks to you/all for any add'l help!

Comment: I fixed the code sample -- I was adding the animation to the UIImage instead of a UIImageView containing a UIImage, which won't work for obvious reasons :-)

Comment: Thanks, Nathan, that does make sense & it does compile now.  Near as I can tell, though, unfortunately, I seem to be back roughly where I started: Trying to do a rotation of, say, 270 degrees (1.5*pi radians) in one direction ... results in a *90 degree* rotation in the opposite direction instead (i.e., the short way 'round)! I believe the answer is with CAKeyframeAnimation rather than CABasicAnimation, as it gives much more control over the actual movement. I'm playing with that, and will post any answer I come up with, or any further questions under a separate post.  Thank you for your time!

Comment: This SO question might give you a few practical hints about how to use CAKeyframeAnimation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929364/how-to-create-iphones-wobbling-icon-effect

Answer (score 1):

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 100, 100);
CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(path, NULL, 100, 100, 100, 615);
CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(path, NULL, 100, 615, 900, 615);
CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(path, NULL, 900, 615, 900, 100);
CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(path, NULL, 900, 100, 100, 80);
CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
pathAnimation.path = path;
pathAnimation.duration = 10.0;
[someLayer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:nil];
```