# How to draw a sinusodial wave which varies with time on a UIView in Objective C?

Tags: uiview, quartz-2d, cgcontext

I want to draw a sinusodial wave which varies with time on a UIView.
 What are the approaches should i take ?
 Any sample code is there ??

Answer (score 1):

I believe the easiest way I've heard of doing what you want to do is using CAKeyframeAnimation.

There is a tutorial page with a sample project here:
http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/parametric-acceleration-curves-in-core.html

There is a stackoverflow about something similar here:
[Basic keyframe animation (rotation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031177/basic-keyframe-animation-rotation)

and the Apple Developer Documentation lists an example application called "MoveMe" that uses keyframe animations

I do not think you have to go all the way to OpenGL for this, but it is certainly capable of this.