# How can I change the UIActivityIndicatorView to set a custom image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, customization, uiactivityindicatorview

Well, I am looking for a way to change my spinner image and use a custom image

Any suggestion?

Comment: i think this is duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010237/creating-a-custom-uiactivityindicatorview

Comment: better watch this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1vWpUwz_xy4

Answer (score 6):

I have created a [subclass of UIActivityIndicatorView](https://github.com/cncool/CDActivityIndicatorView) that allows you to set a custom image.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use a `UIImageView` and add an animation that rotates the view's layer indefinitely. You can achieve this using CoreAnimation. There are plenty of tutorials for this out there.

If you wish to start and stop the animation you can create a simple subclass of `UIImageView` that adds and removes said animation.

Here's a link for the animation: [Basic keyframe animation (rotation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031177/basic-keyframe-animation-rotation)