# how to implement animation on shake effect in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I have implemented one simple application for iphone.now i want to implement some animation.

Example:i have selected one photo from the photo library.Then i want to animate selected portion from the photo using shake effect.

I have seen lots of application in apple store.But i dont know how to implement this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are referring to the "wobble" effect? See [how to create iphone's wobbling icon effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929364/how-to-create-iphones-wobbling-icon-effect)