# How do you create a wiggle animation similar to iphone deletion animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation

We are currently developing an application that contains a series of icons.  We want the icons to wiggle like the app deletion animations when pressed.  What would be the best way to code this animation sequence?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to create iphone's wobbling icon effect?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929364/how-to-create-iphones-wobbling-icon-effect)

Comment: Have a look at this:
[Wobble Effect](https://github.com/rajendrahn/ShakeAnimation)

Answer (score 34):

The answer by Vinzius is very cool. However the wobble only rotates from 0 Radians to 0.08. Thus the wobble can look a little unbalanced. If you get this same issue then you may want to add both a negative and a positive rotation by using a CAKeyframeAnimation rather than a CABasicRotation:

```
- (CAAnimation*)getShakeAnimation 
{
    CAKeyframeAnimation* animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];

    CGFloat wobbleAngle = 0.06f;

    NSValue* valLeft = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeRotation(wobbleAngle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)];
    NSValue* valRight = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeRotation(-wobbleAngle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)];
    animation.values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:valLeft, valRight, nil];

    animation.autoreverses = YES;  
    animation.duration = 0.125;
    animation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;  

    return animation;    
}
```

You can use this animation method for your view or button like this.

```
[self.yourbutton.layer addAnimation:[self getShakeAnimation] forKey:@""];
```

Comment: Great animation, thanks. Tries both of the answers, both is great this one is better for my opinion.

Comment: how to add it to my view or button..?

Answer (score 21):

SWIFT :-

```
let transformAnim  = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath:"transform")
transformAnim.values  = [NSValue(CATransform3D: CATransform3DMakeRotation(0.04, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)),NSValue(CATransform3D: CATransform3DMakeRotation(-0.04 , 0, 0, 1))]
transformAnim.autoreverses = true
transformAnim.duration  = (Double(indexPath.row)%2) == 0 ?   0.115 : 0.105
transformAnim.repeatCount = Float.infinity
self.layer.addAnimation(transformAnim, forKey: "transform")
```

[image]

Objective C :-

```
-(CAKeyframeAnimation *)wiggleView
{
    CAKeyframeAnimation* animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];

    CGFloat wobbleAngle = 0.04f;

    NSValue* valLeft = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeRotation(wobbleAngle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)];
    NSValue* valRight = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeRotation(-wobbleAngle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)];
    animation.values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:valLeft, valRight, nil];

    animation.autoreverses = YES;
    animation.duration = 0.125;
    animation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;

    return animation;
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Looking at the iOS implementation a bit closer, there are two things that make theirs a bit more realistic than the code mentioned here:

- The icons appear to have a bounce as well as a rotation
- Every icon has its own timing -- they are not all synchronized

I based myself on the answers here (and with some help from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14020320/251687)) to add the rotation, the bounce and a bit of randomness to the duration of each animation.

```
#define kWiggleBounceY 4.0f
#define kWiggleBounceDuration 0.12
#define kWiggleBounceDurationVariance 0.025

#define kWiggleRotateAngle 0.06f
#define kWiggleRotateDuration 0.1
#define kWiggleRotateDurationVariance 0.025

-(void)startWiggling {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0
                     animations:^{
                         [self.layer addAnimation:[self rotationAnimation] forKey:@"rotation"];
                         [self.layer addAnimation:[self bounceAnimation] forKey:@"bounce"];
                         self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                     }];
}

-(CAAnimation*)rotationAnimation {
    CAKeyframeAnimation* animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    animation.values = @[@(-kWiggleRotateAngle), @(kWiggleRotateAngle)];

    animation.autoreverses = YES;
    animation.duration = [self randomizeInterval:kWiggleRotateDuration
                                    withVariance:kWiggleRotateDurationVariance];
    animation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;

    return animation;
}

-(CAAnimation*)bounceAnimation {
    CAKeyframeAnimation* animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.y"];
    animation.values = @[@(kWiggleBounceY), @(0.0)];

    animation.autoreverses = YES;
    animation.duration = [self randomizeInterval:kWiggleBounceDuration
                                    withVariance:kWiggleBounceDurationVariance];
    animation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;

    return animation;
}

-(NSTimeInterval)randomizeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)interval withVariance:(double)variance {
    double random = (arc4random_uniform(1000) - 500.0) / 500.0;
    return interval + variance * random;
}
```

I implemented this code on a UICollectionView which had 30 items bouncing and the performance was flawless on an iPad 2.

Comment: This is very close to the Apple Wobble. I just tweaked the constants to these and it seems a bit closer:

#define kWiggleBounceY 3.0f
#define kWiggleBounceDuration 0.14
#define kWiggleBounceDurationVariance 0.025

#define kWiggleRotateAngle 0.03f
#define kWiggleRotateDuration 0.12
#define kWiggleRotateDurationVariance 0.025

Answer (score 11):

I tried to do something like that for an iPad app.

I tried to do some rotations (with CAAnimation) to the view. Here is a sample code I wrote :

```
- (CAAnimation*)getShakeAnimation {

    CABasicAnimation *animation;
    CATransform3D transform;

    // Create the rotation matrix
    transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(0.08, 0, 0, 1.0);

    // Create a basic animation to animate the layer's transform
    animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];

    // Assign the transform as the animation's value
    animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:transform];

    animation.autoreverses = YES;  
    animation.duration = 0.1;  
    animation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;  

    return animation;

}
```

And you should try to apply this one to your layer (with function : addAnimation).
Here, autoreverses property is to alternate left and right orientation.
Try setting others values to the angle and duration.

But in my case I had to add others angles to the CATransform3DMakeRotation method, depending on the initial layer orientation ^^

Good Luck !
Vincent

Answer (score 7):

Rewrote Sebastien's answer in Swift 3.

```
let wiggleBounceY = 4.0
let wiggleBounceDuration = 0.12
let wiggleBounceDurationVariance = 0.025

let wiggleRotateAngle = 0.06
let wiggleRotateDuration = 0.10
let wiggleRotateDurationVariance = 0.025

func randomize(interval: TimeInterval, withVariance variance: Double) -> Double{
    let random = (Double(arc4random_uniform(1000)) - 500.0) / 500.0
    return interval + variance * random
}

func startWiggle(for view: UIView){

    //Create rotation animation
    let rotationAnim = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
    rotationAnim.values = [-wiggleRotateAngle, wiggleRotateAngle]
    rotationAnim.autoreverses = true
    rotationAnim.duration = randomize(interval: wiggleRotateDuration, withVariance: wiggleRotateDurationVariance)
    rotationAnim.repeatCount = HUGE

    //Create bounce animation
    let bounceAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.translation.y")
    bounceAnimation.values = [wiggleBounceY, 0]
    bounceAnimation.autoreverses = true
    bounceAnimation.duration = randomize(interval: wiggleBounceDuration, withVariance: wiggleBounceDurationVariance)
    bounceAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE

    //Apply animations to view
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0) {
        view.layer.add(rotationAnim, forKey: "rotation")
        view.layer.add(bounceAnimation, forKey: "bounce")
        view.transform = .identity
    }
}

func stopWiggle(for view: UIView){
    view.layer.removeAllAnimations()
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
    func startWiggling() {
        deleteButton.isHidden = false
        guard contentView.layer.animation(forKey: "wiggle") == nil else { return }
        guard contentView.layer.animation(forKey: "bounce") == nil else { return }

        let angle = 0.04

        let wiggle = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
        wiggle.values = [-angle, angle]
        wiggle.autoreverses = true
        wiggle.duration = randomInterval(0.1, variance: 0.025)
        wiggle.repeatCount = Float.infinity
        contentView.layer.add(wiggle, forKey: "wiggle")

        let bounce = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.translation.y")
        bounce.values = [4.0, 0.0]
        bounce.autoreverses = true
        bounce.duration = randomInterval(0.12, variance: 0.025)
        bounce.repeatCount = Float.infinity
        contentView.layer.add(bounce, forKey: "bounce")
    }

    func stopWiggling() {
        deleteButton.isHidden = true
        contentView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        }

    func randomInterval(_ interval: TimeInterval, variance: Double) -> TimeInterval {
        return interval + variance * Double((Double(arc4random_uniform(1000)) - 500.0) / 500.0)
    }
```

Look at this iOS SpingBoard [example](https://github.com/tularovbeslan/Springboard.git)

[image: springboard]

Answer (score 3):

Answered in another thread a Swift 4 version of what is apparently Apple's own algorithm reverse engineered: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47730519/5018607

Answer (score 0):

Edited paiego's code to fit my needs: visual error animation feedback upon user's action (tap). It happens once - it's not a constant wiggling like SpringBoard app edit wiggle animation.

```
- (CAAnimation *)shakeAnimation {
    CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];

    CGFloat wobbleAngle = 0.06f;

    NSValue *valLeft;
    NSValue *valRight;
    NSMutableArray *values = [NSMutableArray new];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        valLeft = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeRotation(wobbleAngle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)];
        valRight = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeRotation(-wobbleAngle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)];
        [values addObjectsFromArray:@[valLeft, valRight]];
        wobbleAngle*=0.66;
    }
    animation.values = [values copy];
    animation.duration = 0.7;
    return animation;
}
```

Usage:

```
[your_view.layer addAnimation:[self shakeAnimation] forKey:@""]; //do the shake animation
your_view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity; //return the view back to original
```

Hope this helps someone else.