# iPhone SDK : Create Wiggle Effect

Tags: iphone, sdk, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you create a wiggle animation similar to iphone deletion animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703922/how-do-you-create-a-wiggle-animation-similar-to-iphone-deletion-animation)

Actually this is an answer ! i made tutorial for people who want create wiggle effect with `UIImageView`

The Wiggle Effect Code :

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.14];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:10000];


myImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(69);
myImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-69);

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

to stop the animation you can use this code :

```
myImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);

[myImage.layer removeAllAnimations]; 

//#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> to remove a compiler warning ;)
```

hope you enjoy it .

Comment: Yeah nice but people who are looking for this have already some answer like here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703922/how-do-you-create-a-wiggle-animation-similar-to-iphone-deletion-animation/3704540#3704540 (and some others topics). Maybe you could buzz your youtube video somewhere else. or give the link in appropriate questions.

Comment: By the way, as you edited your topic. You should know that CGAffineTransformMakeRotation take radians and not degrees ( http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html ). (you wrote "myImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(69);", I think you wanted to say 69*M_PI/180.0)

Comment: OK i removed the youtube link ;)and thank you for advise

Comment: You should probably post this as an answer to the linked question.