# Make objects "shake" on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uigesturerecognizer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to create iphone's wobbling icon effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929364/how-to-create-iphones-wobbling-icon-effect)

I'm trying to figure out how to make objects "shake" like when you hold down your finger on apps in the homescreen, so you can move them around and put them in folders.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to create iphone's wobbling icon effect?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929364/how-to-create-iphones-wobbling-icon-effect) or [Create wiggle effect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845111/iphone-sdk-create-wiggle-effect)

Answer (score 0):

The [Three20 Launcher](http://three20.info/showcase/launcher) has this exact function. It's an opensource iOS framework, you could download it, run a demo project and replicate or use their implementation.