# iOS: animation icon model "springboard"

Tags: ios, animation, springboard

I want to know if is possible simulate the little movement of icons in iPhone springboard when I do a long press in one of them. Can you help me?

Comment: There are exact duplicate questions already on StackOverflow (http://stackoverflow.com/q/6604356/558933) and you could also look at the following: http://amro.co/springboard-style-wiggles

Answer (score 1):

LOL!

I was at a conference last year and one of the talkers was an ex Apple employee around at the time of creating that icon wobble.

When they were creating it they used a combination of animation of scale, rotation and translation (both up, down and left, right).

When showing it to Steve Jobs he couldn't be satisfied by any of the wobbles that he was shown.

In the end they created some custom sliders (behind the home screen) that he was able to access so that he could customise the animation himself and get it "just right".

I know this doesn't help at all but thought it might be interesting.

Anyway, it looks like the link that Robotic Cat provided in the comments might give you something worth looking at.