# Combining a UIView perspective transform with other CATranform3Ds

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, core-animation

I'm writing an app such that sprites (subclasses of `UIImageView`) can be rotated, resized, and panned across the screen using gestures. I also would like to be able to apply a 3D perspective transformation to the sprites.

I have the rotate/resize/pan functionality working correctly, as well as the perspective transform. However, they don't seem to work together correctly. If I rotate an unmodified sprite, then try to skew it, the sprite 'resets' it's rotation, then applies the perspective. The opposite works though; if I skew first, I can apply any 2D transformation after without it resetting.

Here is the code I'm using: (rotate, resize, and pan are done using `UIGestureRecognizers`, whereas the skew uses a `UISlider`).

Rotate:

```
- (void)didRotateSprite:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)rotate
{
    CGFloat angle = rotate.rotation;

    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    transform = CATransform3DRotate(spriteView.layer.transform, angle, 0, 0, 1);

    spriteView.layer.transform = transform;

    rotate.rotation = 0.0;
}
```

Resize:

```
- (void)didPinchSprite:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinch
{
    CGFloat scale = pinch.scale;

    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    transform = CATransform3DScale(spriteView.layer.transform, scale, scale, 1);

    view.layer.transform = transform;

    pinch.scale = 1.0;
}
```

Perspective:

```
- (IBAction)perspectiveChanged:(UISlider *)slider
{
    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    transform.m34 = 1.0 / -100;
    transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, (1 - (slider.value * 2)) * M_PI_2, 1, 0, 0);

    spriteView.layer.transform = transform;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer with a lot of debugging and the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016969/ios-simultaneous-scale-and-3d-rotation-animation) question. The trick was to transform the view's perspective using:

`spriteView.superview.layer.sublayerTransform = transform;`

This recursively applies the transformation to the view's superview and any subviews contained in it. For more information about this, check out the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/sublayerTransform) and Apple's [Layer Style Properties guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/LayerStyleProperties/LayerStyleProperties.html) too.