# want to implement the effect of thumbnail removal

Tags: iphone

I want to implement the effect of thumbnail removal. What I want to do is when user touched screen for 2 seconds, that thumbnail start to wobble and a red sign appears in the top left point. then user tap the red sign that thumbnail will be removed.

Is there anyone knows how to implement that?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [[how to create iphone's wobbling icon effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929364/how-to-create-iphones-wobbling-icon-effect)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929364/how-to-create-iphones-wobbling-icon-effect)