# Android - How to create a shake effect like delete in iphone?

Tags: android, animation, effects

I have gridView which has lot of images and on clicking the edit button, I want the images to wobble just like : [how to create iphone's wobbling icon effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929364/how-to-create-iphones-wobbling-icon-effect). Appreciate any pointers to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can start off by modeling the wobble effect as a combination of Animations that Android provides. You can then extend an ImageView and use an `AnimationSet` of this combination of Animations.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an xml that defines how the ImageView will be animated, load the animation in code referencing this xml and then apply it. [A brief documentation here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html).