# I want to create a shaking view like icons on iPhone Home screen, shows delete when touch is hold in Titanium Appcelerator

Tags: iphone, appcelerator-mobile

I am using Titanium Appcelerator framework.

I want to create a button/view which can display 'delete' button in the corner when touch is pressed and held for long time. I have tried with Animation and Transformation but I am not getting it perfectly done. May this be due to false reference to variables or objects.

Please check my code here:
http://pastie.org/3525424

But it's not working. Can anyone please let me know about the issue..?

Answer (score 2):

As vignesh suggested add a UILongPressGesture recognizer and use this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/930101/919545) to give wobbling effect.. this should get you started , you will have to play with the timing of animation though.

Comment: I might have not mentioned that I am working with Titanium Appcelerator framework.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use UILongPressGesture Recognizer registered . You can add a button in the gesture's event. [Apple documentation link](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UILongPressGestureRecognizer) for long press gesture.

Comment: This does not help me because I am writing code with Titanium Appcelerator framework in Javascript language.