# Long press Wobble Effect iPhone

Tags: iphone

I have a tableview, 3 items in a cell, basically I am showing my items in grid view format with 3 columns and I am using tableview for this. This is fine. Now I want to achieve something like when I press any item on tableview/cell for long then all items will wobble and there will be small delete icon on their top left, when user press that icon then that item will be deleted, the way it happens in iPhone home screen.

Now first I want to know is how much feasible is this idea ? Like my only 2 rows will be visible at a time, and tableview reuses cell so if I scroll down and I delete any of the item then it won't create much hassle to manage delete of correct item right? And I want some direction of achieving that long press and wobble effect animation of items. What can I try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the wobbling effect animation code, check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929364/how-to-create-iphones-wobbling-icon-effect).

And for the tableview management,you have to save the `indexpath` on the `layer` property of the `view`.

`[imageView.layer addObject:indexpath forKey:@"indexPath"];`

Now you are able to grab the cell and delete it.

Comment: Hi...i dont want to delete cell row, i want to delete item in a cell row, there will be 3 items in a cell row. Thanks

Comment: No problem..once you grab the cell,you can easily get its subviews.