# UI bar button wobble animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

I figured out how to create a wobble animation with buttons form this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929364/how-to-create-iphones-wobbling-icon-effect). However there is a requirement of `transform` property which is not available in case of uibarbuttonitem. I wish to create this wobbling action for this UIBarButtonItem. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `initWithCustomView:` for the win!

Comment: I thought of this, but as far as I remember, `initWithCustomView` will create a secondary instance of the same, which will not help me, if this is the case. Correct me if i'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[button setTransform:<#(CGAffineTransform)#>]; // SET YOUR TRANSFORM HERE

UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button] autorelease];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton;
```