# Floating bubbles like game center home screen

Tags: ios7, game-center

Tried to find everywhere a similar answer but without satisfaction. I want to make some button inside a floating bubble like the home screen on the notification center. I guess apple uses `UIKitDynamic` to make some effect but can't find the right path.

Do they use Quartz Core or they use Core Animation framework?

I know probably is a silly question but in this site no one asked... (I guess)

Thanks a lot.

Ciao ciao :)

Comment: You want an animated bubble which moves around the screen and has a button inside?

Comment: Hi...thanks for the answer...Yes i want like the home screen of game center...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this Github project: [WobbleBubbleButton](https://github.com/quangtqag/WobbleBubbleButton)

And these SO pages: [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929364/how-to-create-iphones-wobbling-icon-effect) and [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23927047/button-animate-like-ios-game-center-button)

Comment: Yes...thanks a lot that is what I was looking for...thanks a lot man... :)